# How to make a while loop and calculating the average of all positive numbers?

Tags: c#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGMJm.png)

Hi, I need to make a while loop. The code will take all the positive numbers and calculating the average. If 0 is pressed, then the code will stop en the average will be printed. Look at image link. Here is some code:

```
 int input = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
            input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                
            double average = input / 3;

            while (input > 0 )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(input);
                input++;
               
            }
            if (input == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Average of all positive numbers is: {average:0.00} ");
            }
```

Comment: ["_Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?_"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: You are taking the _first_ input and divide it by 3. Then you output it. What else would you expect from that other than seeing 1/3 (rounded towards zero due to integer division) the value of the first input? I mean, you would also see a lot - and i mean a lot - of pointless numbers being outputted there by your while loop (until incrementing `input` overflows and comes back to eventually reaching the value 0) as well. I am afraid to say, but your code doesn't make any sense whatsoever...

Comment: You are reading the number outside the loop. How is that going to work?

Comment: I would suggest you exercise taking the average from a sequence of numbers _in an iterative manner_ with pen and paper first, so that you create a mental model of what you (and eventually your code) need to do. Then, and only then, you start with how you can create such a sequence of numbers in code (with or withour user input). And then, and only then, you deal with how to calculate the average of that sequence of numbers in code.

Comment: (Argh, brain fart in my first comment: The while loop of course exits the moment incrementing of `input` overflows which results in `input` becoming negative. It doesn't need to reach zero for the while to be able to exit. Dang, face palm...)

Comment: You need to calculate the average after the user has entered zero, so that you know what number to divide by (instead of dividing by 3 as you are now). You also need to ignore all negative numbers as you go. 

A couple of ideas on how to do this could be storing all positive numbers in a List<int> and calculate the average at the end, or you could sum the positive numbers as you go while keeping a counter of positive numbers to divide by at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment here is a solution that counts how many positive numbers have been entered and uses that number to divide the result:

```
double count = 0; // Declared as double so fractional value is not lost when dividing the sum
int sum = 0;
int input = -1; // Arbitrarily non-zero number, will be overwritten each loop

while (input != 0)
{
    Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
    input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (input > 0)
    {
        sum += input;
        count++;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine($"Average of all positive numbers is: {sum / count:0.00} ");
```

This initial value of the `input` variable is arbitrary and allows the while loop to run (as the question asked about writing a while loop). This could be rewritten to use a [do...while loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-do-statement) that would run at least once. Then `input` would not need to be initialised at all.